# Printing a calendar from a MySQL database [JSP/Servlet]

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

First of all, sorry for my english, as it's not my native language..

For a school project i'm trying to develop a site listing some student parties, that we insert into a mysql database via a form. 
Now, what i'm trying to do is print the parties in a table to make a calendar-like.

I've searched on google (which led me on some topics here) and i tried, but my code isn't working, and i can't figure why ...

If someone could help me, it would be really appreciated !

My class Soiree :

```
public class Soiree {
private String organisateurs;
private String local;
private String heureDebut;
private String jour;

public void setOrganisateurs(String organisateurs){
    this.organisateurs = organisateurs;
}

public String getOrganisateurs(){
    return organisateurs;
} //And the rest of the setters/getters
```

My servlet Calendrier.java

```
public class Calendrier extends HttpServlet {

public static final String VUE = "/WEB-INF/calendrier.jsp";
private static final String DB_URL ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/projetweb";
private static final String DB_USER = "root";
private static final String DB_PWD = "qsd123qsd";
private static Connection conn;
public static final String ATT_SOIREE = "soiree";


public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ArrayList<Soiree> soirees = new ArrayList<Soiree>();

       try{
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,DB_USER,DB_PWD);
                conn.setAutoCommit(true);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Connection failed" +e.toString());
            }

            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT organisateurs,local,jour,heure from soirees order by jour");


            while(rs.next()){
                Soiree soiree = new Soiree();
                soiree.setOrganisateurs(rs.getString("organisateurs"));
                soiree.setLocal(rs.getString("local"));
                soiree.setHeure(rs.getString("heure"));
                soiree.setJour(rs.getString("jour"));
                soirees.add(soiree);
            }


       }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception in verifyPasswd " + e.toString());

        }
        request.setAttribute(ATT_SOIREE, soirees);
            /* Transmission de la paire d'objets request/response à notre JSP */
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( VUE ).forward( request, response );

}
```

}

And finally my Calendrier.jsp (only the relevant part to print) :

```
<c:foreach var="soirees" items="${soirees }" >
                <c:out value="${soirees.organisateurs }" />
                <c:out value="${soirees.local }" />
                <c:out value="${soirees.heureDebut }" />
                <c:out value="${soirees.jour }" />
            </c:foreach>
```

PS: Sorry for the long post !

Comment: Nothing more, sadly =/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `s` to `ATT_SOIREE`

```
public static final String ATT_SOIREE = "soirees";
```

and remove the space to match the corresponding EL variable (along with all the other spaces)

```
<c:foreach var="soiree" items="${soirees}" >
        ${soiree.organisateurs}<br>
        ${soiree.local}<br> 
        ${soiree.heureDebut}<br>
        ${soiree.jour}<br>
</c:foreach>
```

Comment: Still not working ..
I'm really not a pro with JSP/Servlet (it was almost only self-learning, our teacher kind of failed his class), so i don't even know, is the global structure fine for what i'm trying to do ?

Comment: Did you debug your servlet code? Are objects being added to the `List`?

Comment: Sorry again, but how can i do that ?

Comment: You can use a plugin like [eclipsetotale](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) if youre using Eclipse. If not you can add temporary `println` statements to the servlet iteration. Did you remove _all_ the spaces from the `EL` variables btw? (see update)

Comment: I'm now getting this error :

Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [Calendrier] in context with path [/webproject] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/calendrier.jsp at line 46


44:              
45:              <c:foreach var="soirees" items="${soirees }" >
46:               <c:out value="${soirees.organisateurs 
And all the others c:out

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "organisateurs"

Comment: I guess the error is coming from using an ArrayList and it's trying to get it as a String, but i can't find any solutions for that ...

Comment: Post the stacktrace in the question. Also try printing out the entries as they are added to the list to ensure that the list is not empty

Comment: How do i get the stacktrace ? (i'm not going that far in programming on a regular basis ..) I'll edit the first post when i'll get it.
I've tried with some system.out.println, seems like the list is not empty. I guess it's normal that it's printing some Soiree@75b6 etc, it's the address of the data ?

Comment: Thats the `Object#toString` representation of the object. The stacktrace is error message that you posted as a comment 3 hours ago. Along with the above changes, your code looks ok now so I'll be deleting this post soon...